# Removing text from multiple <p> tags from each <article> in xml

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I'm struggling with this problem with a large xml file with a root of 'articles' and containing many individual articles under the tag 'article>. What I'm hoping to do is for each 'article' in 'articles' collect all text within the 'p' tags. An 'article' can have multiple 'p' tags as illustrated in below:

```
<articles>
    <article title="Blah" published-at="2018-01-01" id="00000">
      <p>Here is some text.</p>
      <p>Another line of text.</p>
      <a type="external" href="https://www.website.com/">Image</a>
      <p>Final line of text.</p>
    </article>
    <article title="Second blah" published-at="2018-01-02" id="00001">
      <p>Here is some new text.</p>
      <p>Final line of new text.</p>
    </article>
</articles>
```

So what I wanted to do was iterate over each article and generate a single line containing all text in the 'p' tags, not caring if I picked up the links and associated text in the 'a' tags.

I was hoping something like this would work but it produced a text file that was not separated by each respective 'article'

```
text = []

for p in root.iter('p'):
  text.append(p.text)
  with open("text.txt", "w", encoding = 'utf-8') as output:
    output.write(str(text))
```

Any help would be sincerely appreciated as this is a very difficult question for me to express in a search.

Answer (score 0):

Python has [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) library (among others) for working with XML and with it you can do:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

text = []
for article in root.findall('article'):
    for paragraph in article.findall('p'):
        text.append(paragraph.text)
        paragraph.text = ''

tree.write('output.xml')
```